# Как плавно скрыть QWidget, чтобы родительский QWidget также уменьшался?

Tags: python, pyqt5, анимация, pyside2, qpropertyanimation

Мне нужно, чтобы `QWidget "mini_window"` менял свою высоту
с обычной на **`0`** и наоборот, когда была нажата кнопка `"click_me"`.
И родительский `QWidget "main_winow"` подстраивал свой размер.

Я использовал `QPropertyAnimation` из урока по Qt5. 
Я пытался изменить максимальный размер `"mini_window"`, но я не нашел такого параметра в `QPropertyAnimation`, поэтому я просто использовал (`size`)

Но после нажатия на кнопку мой `QWidget "main_winow"` остается того же размера, а компановка не обновляется.

Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

```
from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter, QPixmap,
    QRadialGradient)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *  
from PySide2.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, QRect
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget
import sys
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet(u"#centralwidget QWidget QWidget,\n"
"#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,\n"
"#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{\n"
"background:#000;\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"#centralwidget QWidget,\n"
"#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,\n"
"#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{\n"
"background:#fff;\n"
"color:#000;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.main_winow = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.main_winow.setObjectName(u"main_winow")
        self.main_winow.setGeometry(QRect(50, 30, 141, 131))
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.main_winow)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.click_me = QPushButton(self.main_winow)
        self.click_me.setObjectName(u"click_me")
        self.click_me.clicked.connect(self.doAnimation) 
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.click_me)
        self.mini_window = QWidget(self.main_winow)
        self.mini_window.setObjectName(u"mini_window")      
        self.mini_window.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 16777215))          
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.mini_window)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.text_label = QLabel(self.mini_window)
        self.text_label.setObjectName(u"text_label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.text_label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.mini_window)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.click_me.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Click me", None))
        self.text_label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Text", None))
    def doAnimation(self):
        self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.mini_window, b"size")
        self.anim.setDuration(1000) #speed
        self.anim.setStartValue(QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.anim.setEndValue(QSize(16777215, 0))
        self.anim.start()
class QtMainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtMainWindow()
    window.show()
sys.exit(my.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я перенес всю логику в `class QtMainWindow`. **Вам надо только поменять импорты**, т.к. у `PyQt5`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

        if MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")

        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet(u"#centralwidget QWidget QWidget,\n"

"#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,\n"
"#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{\n"
"background:#000;\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"#centralwidget QWidget,\n"
"#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,\n"
"#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{\n"
"background:#fff;\n"
"color:#000;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.main_winow = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.main_winow.setObjectName(u"main_winow")
        self.main_winow.setGeometry(QRect(50, 30, 141, 131))

        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.main_winow)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")

        self.click_me = QPushButton(self.main_winow)
        self.click_me.setObjectName(u"click_me")
#        self.click_me.clicked.connect(self.doAnimation) 
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.click_me)

        self.mini_window = QWidget(self.main_winow)
        self.mini_window.setObjectName(u"mini_window")      
#        self.mini_window.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 16777215))  
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.mini_window)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.text_label = QLabel(self.mini_window)
        self.text_label.setObjectName(u"text_label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.text_label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.mini_window)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.click_me.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Click me", None))
        self.text_label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Text", None))


class QtMainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.click_me.setText('Скрыть `mini_window`')                      # +++
        self.click_me.clicked.connect(self.doAnimation)                    # +++
        QTimer.singleShot(10, self.size_mini_window)                       # +++

    def size_mini_window(self):                                            # +++
        self.s = self.mini_window.size()

    def doAnimation(self):                                                 # +++
        if self.click_me.text() == 'Скрыть `mini_window`':
            self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.mini_window, b"size")
            self.anim.setDuration(1500) 
            self.anim.setStartValue(self.s)
            self.anim.setEndValue(QSize(self.s.width(), 0))
            self.anim.start()
            self.click_me.setText('Показать `mini_window`')
        else:
            self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.mini_window, b"size")
            self.anim.setDuration(1500) 
            self.anim.setStartValue(QSize(self.s.width(), 0))
            self.anim.setEndValue(self.s)
            self.anim.start()
            self.click_me.setText('Скрыть `mini_window`')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtMainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(my.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можно ли как нибудь обновить всю компоновку которая находится радом с mini_window? Я имею в веду если mini_window уменьшается то и main_winow тоже должен уменьшется как здесь https://ibb.co/WHf177S что у меня https://ibb.co/5YxQNcx

Comment: @orlatym вы привели пример, задали вопрос. Я вам предложил вариант решения. У вас есть новый приме и вопрос - тогда вам надо `Задать новый вопрос`.

Comment: @ S.Nick Чисто технически вопрос тот же. Абзац 4 **Но после нажатия на кнопку мой Qwidget "main_winow" остается того же размера, а компановка не обновляется.** Просто я добавил немного внешней компановки что бы подчеркнуть что я имею в веду. [Ну ладно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1080320/qwidget)